# Pepper plants developing strange leaves

Tags: peppers

My pepper plants are at various stages of growth but nearly all of them are developing these really strange leaves that are curved downwards, elongated and hard to the touch.

I can't figure out what it is. This is most prevelent in my hydroponic Scorpian pepper plant where I pruned it but all the new leaves are coming out this way.

Could this be over fertilisation? Why would I have that in my other soil plants too though?

Image Links:

[My Pepper Plants (1)](https://ibb.co/ijqdra)

[My Pepper Plants (2)](https://ibb.co/gtZtPv)

[image: pepper plants]

[image: pepper plants]

Please Help. Can't find the answer to this!

Thanks
K

Comment: This picture does not show over fertilization.  What have you done for fertilizer?  What are those 'rocks' on the top of the soil?  Is this hydroponics or peppers grown in potting soil?  Need to know what you have added to your system.  Your plants look in dire need of proper chemistry to make their own food for energy.  Do you smoke?  Possibly a virus as well that is transferred from tobacco.  Please give more detail so that we are better able to answer!  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thanks! No I don't smoke. Those aren't 'rocks', those are hydroton (clay pebbles). That's the Hydroponic system which seems to be having the most problem. It was ok till a few days ago, until I increased the fertilizer quantity a bit (the root system is substantial) and then all these new leaves are coming out like this! The strange part is that I haven't fertilized the plants that are in soil since they are pretty young, but 3 of them have a leaf or two that look like this as well. I'm hoping it's not a virus since my bhut seems to be sprouting some normal leaves now.

Comment: Can you add the pictures to your question -  the link is not working

Comment: Return the fertilizer to the original amount before this started to happen.  See what changes.

Comment: If it's just the new leaves, I'd guess either a virus or an immobile nutrient imbalance. Is it just the new leaves?

Answer (score 3):

This is the silver mite damage on your pepper plant. These are very small in size and can be seen under a magnifying glass. These mites suck the sap from cells on the underside of the leaves, resulting leaves that bend downward.
Management: Spay miticide to kill the mites.

Comment: Although I agree that it's probably a mite of some sort, do you have a source with regard to silver mites and peppers? I haven't yet found anything on them with peppers (but peaches), but I have with broad mites (although I'm not sure this is a broad mite problem, as I don't see any purple on the leaves). It doesn't look like spider mites, particularly, although I know they afflict peppers, and maybe different kinds of spider mites look different.

Comment: Hi! I noticed you have a couple of user accounts, one registered and one unregistered. There are some advantages to [merging them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!